# How to always show the infowindow in a marker in google maps Subgurim?

Tags: google-maps, subgurim-maps

Here is our code using the Google Maps Subgurim

```
GInfoWindow window1 = new GInfoWindow(icon1, "bin 1", false, Glistener.Event.mouseover);
GMap1.Add(window1);

GInfoWindow window2 = new GInfoWindow(icon1, "bin 2", false, Glistener.Event.mouseover)
GMap1.Add(window2);
```

and what we want to do is that the infowindow of both markers are always open instead of hovering the mouse on the marker? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://en.googlemaps.subgurim.net/ejemplos/ejemplo_900_InfoWindow-con-icono.aspx) says about third parameter passed to `GInfoWindow` constructor:

> openedOnLoad: indicates whether the InfoWindow will be open when the
>   map is loaded, if not, you can open it by executing the chosen event
>   above the icon. It is open by default.

Meaning, changing third parameter from `false` to `true` should be enough:

```
GInfoWindow window1 = new GInfoWindow(icon1, "bin 1", true, Glistener.Event.mouseover);
```